# Java PhantomJS with Ghost Driver Working on Mac But Not On Linux

Tags: java, linux, phantomjs, ghost

our web application is running fine on mac but getting timeout out exception ON linux. I am using phantomJS 1.9.8 and 1.9.7.  Below is Java Code and stack trace.
Hi,
our web application is running fine on mac but getting timeout out exception ON linux. I am using phantomJS 1.9.8 and 1.9.7.  Below is Java Code and stack trace.
Hi,
our web application is running fine on mac but getting timeout out exception ON linux. I am using phantomJS 1.9.8 and 1.9.7.  Below is Java Code and stack trace.

```
File scrFile=null;
WebDriver driver=null;
try{
// Initiation caps from spring dependency.
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, pathToPhantomJS);
        caps.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", pathToPhantomJS);
        caps.setCapability(IscoreConstants.TAKE_SCREEN_SHOT, true);

        LOGGER.info("Getting Driver Instance .");
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        LOGGER.info("Driver Instance Created.");

Stack Trace:

[DATE=&quot;2015-07-01 00:02:17,254&quot;] [LEVEL=ERROR] [LOG_MODULE=com.apple.gbi.gsf.web.handler.ServiceExceptionHandler] [ReqId=&quot;&quot;] [LOG_MESSAGE=&quot;[REQUEST-INFO="uri=/gsf/iScore/businessareas/applecare/subjectareas/contactcenter/proxy/CaptureImage;client=17.169.113.85;session=Q1zben8C30t05Oab2SFjazP8 (user-agent:curl/7.37.1;host:gsf-dev2.corp.apple.com;content-type:application/json;accept:application/json;content-length:150;x-forwarded-for:17.149.233.4;vip-ip-port:17.161.20.239_443)"] [REQID="60943584-efd8-4a67-9e08-6fc46e98912f"] [ERRORCODE="ISR01012"] [ERRORMSG="Error Occoured While Capturing Image"] : com.apple.gbi.gsf.api.exception.ServiceException$UnexpectedException: Error Occoured While Capturing Image
    at com.apple.gbi.iscore.service.screencapture.ScreenCaptureServiceImpl.captureImage(ScreenCaptureServiceImpl.java:85)
    at com.apple.gbi.iscore.proxy.imagecapture.CaptureImageProxyService.execute(CaptureImageProxyService.java:42)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.core.proxy.ProxyDataService.executeService(ProxyDataService.java:38)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.core.service.AbstractDataService.getData(AbstractDataService.java:35)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.query.staticquery.service.ServiceExecutorImpl.execute(ServiceExecutorImpl.java:479)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.query.staticquery.service.ServiceExecutorImpl.execute(ServiceExecutorImpl.java:470)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.web.controller.service.query.ServiceController.executeServiceRequest(ServiceController.java:231)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.web.controller.service.query.ServiceController.query(ServiceController.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:389)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:847)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ma-bobjd-lapp10.corp.apple.com', ip: '10.185.20.170', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.39-400.214.4.el6uek.x86_64', java.version: '1.6.0_32'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at com.apple.gbi.iscore.service.screencapture.ScreenCaptureServiceImpl.captureImage(ScreenCaptureServiceImpl.java:61)
    at com.apple.gbi.iscore.proxy.imagecapture.CaptureImageProxyService.execute(CaptureImageProxyService.java:42)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.core.proxy.ProxyDataService.executeService(ProxyDataService.java:38)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.core.service.AbstractDataService.getData(AbstractDataService.java:35)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.query.staticquery.service.ServiceExecutorImpl.execute(ServiceExecutorImpl.java:479)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.query.staticquery.service.ServiceExecutorImpl.execute(ServiceExecutorImpl.java:470)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.web.controller.service.query.ServiceController.executeServiceRequest(ServiceController.java:231)
    at com.apple.gbi.gsf.web.controller.service.query.ServiceController.query(ServiceController.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:389)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:847)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ma-bobjd-lapp10.corp.apple.com', ip: '10.185.20.170', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.39-400.214.4.el6uek.x86_64', java.version: '1.6.0_32'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:9011/status] to be available after 20001 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
```